# IIS v6.0 SMTP Default 'From' Address

Tags: iis, email, smtp

we have an SMTP server in IIS 6.0 which has the default 'from' address in the following format:

ServerName@domain.com

it is a basic setup. we have a .net application using this SMTP server as needed to fire emails to customers.

We have been altering the 'from' address within the .net web application. this, however has flagged as SPAM to a number of ISP's (AOL in particular)

to get around this, we have removed the 'from' mask we were using but we want to alter the settings of the SMTP server to send emails from a more generic address... such as

bob@domain.com

what would be the best way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

u need to use the smtp server which will be hosted on same server as domain.com

otherwise most of the ISPs will mark it as spam as it is sent on behalf of some other email address